# Use the 'offset' method to reference a cell in another worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, offset

I'm working on a routine that will populate a worksheet from data on a second worksheet in the same active workbook. The location on the destination worksheet is relative to a given cell which is the active cell on the relevant worksheet. In order to avoid continually swapping between active sheets, I was hoping that I could reference the destination cell using the 'offset' method, however I can't get it to work. My code line would be something like this:

```
Worksheets("DestinationSheet").activecell.offset(Rowoffset:=x, ColumnOffset:=y).Value=DataValue
```

Where x, y, and Datavalue are variables.

Comment: `Worksheets("DestinationSheet").Range(ActiveCell.Address)`...

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
Worksheets("DestinationSheet").range(activecell.address).offset(Rowoffset:=x, ColumnOffset:=y).Value=DataValue
```

?

The `activecell` is only a single cell on the active sheet so cannot be located on another sheet (and that sheet must be active when the macro is run). Btw it's not a good idea to base code on the activecell if you can avoid it.

That said, I'm not sure I understand what you are doing.

Comment: Thank you, that answers the question completely. It is clear that Excel retains the location of the activecell on a non-active sheet and I was hoping that there was some way to reference that location without selecting the sheet. Clearly this isn't the case. I'll have to go to plan B...